# Node: child_process.exec() process continuing after parent process dies

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, child-process

I'm trying to get create a local API service for testing purposes, which involves running a make command in my build system. The code looks like this:

(note: this is in coffeescript)

```
request = require "request"
child_process = require "child_process"
tsc = require "training_service_connector"

campaign = "happytest"
strategy = campaign
port_number = 54340
service_conf_filename = tsc.writeServiceConfig(strategy, port_number)
exec_callback = (error, stdout, stderr) -> 
    console.log ('stdout:\n' + stdout + '\nstderr:\n' + stderr + "\nerror:\n" + error)
child_process.exec ("CONFIG=#{service_conf_filename} make run_bidder_service_runner", exec_callback)

# some other stuff
```

Now, in trying to figure out how to get the rest of the test to run AFTER the API goes up (ugh async), I've been running this code in a REPL. The REPL is buggy, and so I have to use ctrl+Z to kill it a lot. After killing the process, it seems the child process is still running...

```
lsof -i :54340
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python  52650  max    3u  IPv4 20606263      0t0  TCP localhost:54340 (LISTEN)
```

Now if I try to run it again, I get an error saying the port is already in use. Why doesn't the child process die with the parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different operating systems handle child processes differently.  I usually add in handler like this:

```
['SIGINT', 'SIGHUP', 'SIGTERM'].forEach(function(signal) {
    process.addListener(signal, gracefulShutdown);
});
```

`gracefulShutdown` should do things like close sockets and quit processes (`process.stop()`)

OH... And I just reread your question.  ctrl-z pauses a process, it doesn't kill it.  If you use `fg` or `bg`, it will bring the process back into the foreground/background.  To quick the REPL, use ctrl-c twice.